# hsqldb table data not loading in in-process mode

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I am using hibernate and HSQLDB. HSQLDB works in in-process mode.

The database query:

```java
    session.createQuery("from Doctor").list();
```

returns an empty list. But, in reality, the database tables are not empty and all database files are in project package

[image]

hibernate configuration:

```xml
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <!-- In-Process database connection-->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:demodb;shutdown=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">user1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="com.mycom.entity.Doctor"></mapping>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JDBC URL opens the database in the directory where the Java VM was started. You need to use either an absolute path to the database or a path that contains a placeholder for the `user.home` directory if you put the files there.

See: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_variables_url

Comment: All database files in procject package

Comment: Check where the Java VM is is started. It may not be the same place as your files.

Comment: yes, indeed, the absolute path to the database file (demodb without extension) works